# Boolean Cutting is not Working

Tags: modifiers

I have been working on this for like 5 hours but still can't figure it out. I want to use the plane and the Boolean Modifier to remove the end of the nose from the elephant, but it doesn't seem to work, and either the plane is gone or the size of the nose cuts the plane.

I have attached the file, if anyone could help that would be great! Sorry for the trouble once again, thanks in advance.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1atL5yEH1WCgFQqHJp0WW-m-y0HmZfVwZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Booleans are a volume-based operation

Literally, boolean is about doing simple maths between two volumes. Like `A + B` or `A - B`.
A plane has zero volume. So you're asking Blender to do the maths `A - 0`... Which equals A.

If you want to remove the end of the nose, extrude your plane so it contains all the parts you want to cut off:

[image: boolean volume example]

#### The modifier must be set on the target final object

Your goal is to have your elephant without its nose, so it's the elephant object that should wear the boolean modifier:

[image: boolean target example]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the clear explanation! I didn't really get how booleans were in Blender at the start, but now I do. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a boolean between the Elephant and a cube, not a single plane.

[image]

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help!